# Extended Metadata File (JSON) contains {} only

Tags: json, einstein-analytics

I'm trying to download the Extended Metadata File (JSON) for a Wave Analytics dataset and after download the file contains {} only and no other content. Any idea why this may be happening? Any suggested solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Metadata File is a place for ADDITIONAL customisation. It will be empty by default until you add your settings there.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed this was the case as I researched more. Salesforce's documentation doesn't seem to make this important clarification. I appreciate your help!